# How to find "slow" places when building a solution on VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, build-process, profiler

Is there an instrument that can find me a place in my project which takes so long to build? Like performance profiler, but for the build process of Visual Studio.

P.S. I tried profiling my Visual Studio during build with another instance of VS, but I didn't get obvious results.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but just a tip: Using a RamDrive reduced build time (on a build server) dramatically at a company I worked for. It took one third of the time compared to using the hard drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run
```

There you can change the 
`MSBUild project build output verbosity`
 settings

When on **normal** level it will give timings for each project, so this could be used to see what is causing the slow down. (in the Output window)

On a higher level you will see even more detail of what is going on during a compile.

Answer (score 5):

I got better results with http://msbuildprofiler.codeplex.com/ then compile my solution in a msbuild prompt

```
MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:rebuild /l:MSBuildProfileLogger,MSBuildProfiler,Version=1.0.1.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=09544254e89d148c
```

Just be careful to run rebuild target (/t:rebuild) otherwise you get completely different results second time you run it.

I think $1 donation is good price :)